# xtrabackup "failed to read metadata"

Tags: mysql, percona, backup, xtrabackup

Doing a staging run setting up a new xtrabackup restore script I'm running into a somewhat cryptic error I can't readily google a solution for.

I'm working with an incremental backup design.  During the initial copy back of the last full the an attempt to apply changes to the first incremental is failing with

```
xtrabackup: error: failed to read metadata from 
/var/tmp/mysql_backups/inc/day1/xtrabackup_checkpoints
```

The cited file is present and world readable.

It's contents are

```
backup_type = incremental
from_lsn = 12:4121088784
to_lsn = 12:4121089203
last_lsn = 12:4121089203
```

Thoughts on what to check from here?

**Edit**

I think I found my problem.  My testing server install was an ubuntu mysql default; not percona.

https://bugs.launchpad.net/percona-xtrabackup/+bug/655584/comments/3

Comment: I'm closing this because it is unlikely to ever help anyone else - it is too specific

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I found my problem. My testing server install was an ubuntu mysql default; not percona.

https://bugs.launchpad.net/percona-xtrabackup/+bug/655584/comments/3